# Any starter kit or sample to use TypeScript in IBM Cloud Functions / OpenWhisk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I am developing actions in IBM Cloud Functions and so far have used Node.js / Javascript and Python for coding. I haven't seen instructions on how to use TypeScript with IBM Cloud Functions.

What is the recommended way of using TypeScript, is it to deploy a Docker container or can I use it similar to (more or less) simple JavaScript actions? Any starter packages or samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following guidelines so far:

- This blog describes [using TypeScript in a Docker container with OpenWhisk / IBM Cloud Functions](http://heidloff.net/article/serverless-functions-typescript-openwhisk)
- A second approach is to directly compile and bundle TypeScript actions using webpack and deploy via [wskdeploy](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-wskdeploy). It is described in this [IBM Cloud Functions TypeScript Starter](https://github.com/van-ibm/cloud-functions-typescript/) and the related blog on [building IBM Cloud Functions with TypeScript](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/08/building-ibm-cloud-functions-with-typescript/). It even has instructions on unit testing with Mocha.

Comment: There is no direct support for typescript yet. Compiling the source to JavaScript then creating a node action would be the better path forward to avoid creating a docker action.

Comment: Isn't that what the second approach does?